# Listing CoreData object through Relationship

Tags: swift, core-data

I had this working without CoreData relationships (multiple fetches), but it occurred to me that I should probably have relationships between these entities implemented, so that I can just fetch from a single entity to get all attributes.

When I fetch accountNames from the Accounts entity directly for my AccountsList.swift (to create accounts) - it works just fine, but when I try to call them through the relationship (originAccounts), it doesn't show anything in the list. Same issue for the Categories picker.

I have 3 CoreData entities, and two Pickers (for category and account)

**Expenses**

- expenseAccount:String
- expenseCategory:String
- expenseCost:Double
- expenseDate:Date
- expenseId:UUID
- expenseIsMonthly:Bool
- expenseName:String

**Categories**

- categoryName:String

**Accounts**

- accountName:String

Expenses has a many to one relationship with both Accounts and Categories

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ExpenseDetail: View {
    
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Expenses.expensesList)
    var results: FetchedResults<Expenses>
    
    
    
    var logToEdit: Expenses?
    
    @State var name: String = ""
    @State var amount: String = ""
    @State var category: String?
    @State var date: Date = Date()
    @State var account: String?
    @State var isMonthly: Bool = false
    
    var currencyFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let f = NumberFormatter()
        f.numberStyle = .currency
        return f
    }()
    
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form{
                TextField("Expense Name", text: $name)
                Section{
                    HStack{
                        TextField("$\(amount)", text: $amount)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                            .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                            .disableAutocorrection(true).multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                    DatePicker(selection: $date, displayedComponents: .date) {
                        Text("Date")
                    }.onAppear{self.hideKeyboard()}
                    
                    
                    
                    Picker(selection: $category, label: Text("Category")) {
                        ForEach(results) { (log: Expenses) in
                            Text(log.originCategories?.categoryName ?? "No Category").tag(log.originCategories?.categoryName)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Picker(selection: $account, label: Text("Account")) {
                        ForEach(results) { (log: Expenses) in
                            Text(log.originAccounts?.accountName ?? "No Account").tag(log.originAccounts?.accountName)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Toggle(isOn: $isMonthly) {
                        Text("Monthly Expense")
                    }.toggleStyle(CheckboxToggleStyle())
                }
                
                Section{
                    Button(action: {
                        onSaveTapped()
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Save")
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                }
                Section{
                    Button(action: {
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Cancel").foregroundColor(.red)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Add Expense")
        }
        
    }
    
    private func onSaveTapped() {
        
        let expenseLog: Expenses
        if let logToEdit = self.logToEdit {
            expenseLog = logToEdit
        } else {
            expenseLog = Expenses(context: self.context)
            expenseLog.expenseId = UUID()
        }
        
        expenseLog.expenseName = self.name
        expenseLog.originCategories?.categoryName = self.category
        expenseLog.expenseCost = Double(self.amount) ?? 0
        expenseLog.expenseDate = self.date
        expenseLog.originAccounts?.accountName = self.account
        print("\(self.account ?? "NoAccountValue")")
        expenseLog.expenseIsMonthly = self.isMonthly
        
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
    
    
}

#if canImport(UIKit)
extension View {
    func hideKeyboard() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
#endif

struct ExpenseDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExpenseDetail()
        
    }
    
}

struct CheckboxToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        return HStack {
            configuration.label
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: configuration.isOn ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                .onTapGesture { configuration.isOn.toggle() }
        }
    }
}
```

expensesList fetch details, if needed

```
    static var expensesList: NSFetchRequest<Expenses> {
      let request: NSFetchRequest<Expenses> = Expenses.fetchRequest()
      request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "expenseName", ascending: true)]
      return request
    }
```

Comment: You can't fill the Picker with categories used by existing Expenses objects, they need to be filled with all categories using a separate fetch request for Categories so the user can select from all of them (and same for Accounts).

Comment: Thanks @JoakimDanielson! This definitely clarifies fetch requests for me. I'm clearly new at this so I appreciate the help.

I do have one issue now. I have a separate view for the ExpenseList. Account name (log.originAccounts?.accountName?) is blank there as well. Am I calling this value incorrectly?


                                    Text(log.originAccounts?.accountName?.capitalized ?? "").font(.caption)

Comment: That look correct to me